# How to turn on/off the embla carousel by breakpoint in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, embla-carousel

Using the [Embla Carousel](https://www.embla-carousel.com/), [React version](https://www.embla-carousel.com/get-started/react), I'm trying to turn/on off the carousel based on breakpoint. So for mobile, it's on and for tablet up it's off. Here's what I tried that seems to work initially, but won't reinitialize. I'm guessing it's because `destory` was called so it can reInit and tried `init`, but no luck there either.

```
const emblaOptions = {};
  const [viewportRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel(emblaOptions);

  const handleEmblaInit = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
      emblaApi.destroy();
    } else {
      emblaApi.reInit(emblaOptions);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (emblaApi) {
      handleEmblaInit();
      window.addEventListener("resize", handleEmblaInit);
    }
  }, [emblaApi]);
```

Answer (score 2):

From **version 7 and up** you can use the [active option](https://www.embla-carousel.com/api/options/#active) together with the [breakpoints option](https://www.embla-carousel.com/api/options/#breakpoints) to achieve this. [Example from the Embla Carousel docs](https://www.embla-carousel.com/guides/breakpoints/#changing-options):

```js
const options = {
  active: true,
  breakpoints: {
    '(min-width: 768px)': { active: false },
  },
}
```

Usage with React:

```js
const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel({
  active: true,
  breakpoints: {
    '(min-width: 768px)': { active: false },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass null instead of the emblaRef when you want it to be inactive, like demonstrated here:

https://github.com/davidcetinkaya/embla-carousel/issues/99#issuecomment-688730519